# How to find TP,TN, FP and FN values from 8x8 Confusion Matrix

Tags: weka, confusion-matrix

I have confusion matrix as follow:

```
   a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h   <-- classified as

 1086    7    1    0    2    4    0    0 |    a

    7 1064    8    6    0    2    2    0 |    b

    0    2 1091    2    3    0    1    1 |    c

    0    8    0 1090    1    1    0    0 |    d

    1    1    1    1  597    2    2    0 |    e

    4    2    1    0    3 1089    0    1 |    f

    0    2    1    3    0    0  219    0 |    g

    0    0    1    0    1    4    1  443 |    h
```

Now how to find the True positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative values from this confusion matrix.
The Weka gave me TP Rate is that same as True positive value ?

[image: Can we consider summation of the RED bordered area as TN value for class 'a'?]

Can we consider summation of the RED bordered area as TN value for class 'a'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True Positive, True Negative, False Positive, and False Negative are defined for binary classification problems (in which one outcome is defined as "positive" and the other "negative").

So to use this terminology as a measure of success for a larger confusion matrix, you must break the table down into a series of binary classification sub-tables.

For example, we could calculate the TP, TN, FP, and FN for class A.  This breaks down as follows

- TP: True A's that are correctly classified as A
- TN: All other classes correctly classified as not A
- FP: Other classes incorrectly classified as A
- FN: A's that were incorrectly classified as not A

This could then be repeated for all classes to get a TP, TN, FP, and FN conditional on each actual class.

Alternatively, you could use a measure calculated on the table as a whole such as overall accuracy.  More sophisticated measures can also be calculated to evaluate purity of the classification.  This Stack Overflow link provides a good start for investigating some of these methods: [how to calculate classification error rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067118/how-to-calculate-classification-error-rate)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the question arises what to consider as a TN for NxN Matrix. In case of above example that I have posted for class 'a' TN value will be ? Edit: Have added the more detailed view in question.

Comment: That's correct, the summation of the red box represents the TN's for class A.  Any actual class that is classified as not-A is a TN when treating A as a positive.